# why retainCount increased?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _testObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"_testObject rc = %d", _testObject.retainCount);
    NSLog(@"testObject rc = %d", self.testObject.retainCount);
}
```

And testObject is

```
@property (retain) TestObject *testObject;
```

Why is the output of these `NSLog()` 1 and 2, respectively? The `retainCount` of a property and the underlying object is different?

Comment: Could you copy-paste the second line `NSLog(@"testObject rc = %d", self.testObject.retainCount);` several times and try it out? Will you always get 2, or does the count go up? Just curious... If it goes up, you've got a retain/autorelease property.

Comment: have found the reason, didn't add nonatomic.

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that it's because your property isn't defined as `nonatomic`, so you're getting a retained/autoreleased object. Try changing your property declaration to this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) TestObject *testObject;
```

Comment: I do not see the relevance of atomic access, here. Could you explain?

Comment: Ah, I follow now. I'd forgotten the details of the synthesized setter for atomic properties. Here's [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Comment: For other people reading this who are stil confused: `atomic` properties add an amount of thread safety by ensuring the object underneath can't be modified while you're accessing it.